# Extract image pixel values from a coarser raster

Tags: python, image, numpy, gdal

I have 2 images. Image_1 has a resolution of 250 m and image_2 has a resolution of 500m. These images have the exact same spatial content and projection.

How would I overlay these two images, so that for each pixel in image_1, I can extract the pixel value from image 2? I tried gdal reprojectimage (reproject image 2), but it does resampling with interpolation. This won't work for me, since resampling will change the pixel values in image_2. Is there any efficient way to do this? Scipy, numpy, or any similar tools will be great.

Comment: I don't really get want to do exactly. If you just want to have every other pixel from image_2 then image_2[::2, ::2] will do it for you. (each dimension can be given a slice with (start:stop:skip). so if you do "::2" this means no special value for Start none for Stop but a skip of 2 --> skipping every other pixel) I have a feeling however that is not what you were asking, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the resampling method to nearest neighbor, which is of course still a way of interpolating, but i think that the result is exactly what you're after. If you use gdalwarp you can output to a VRT which you can then open in Python.

Alternatively you can also scale up the array in Python directly, but this will only be valid if indeed all the spatial properties are identical.

It can be done with Numpy like:

```
image2_250m = np.kron(image2_500m, np.ones((2,2)))
```

That scales it up a factor of 2 in both dimensions. If you also have a third dimension containing bands you want to use `np.ones((1,2,2))` which would scale the band/spectral dimension with 1 (eg do nothing). Its still a form of nearest neighbor interpolation

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.random.randint(0,100, (2,2))

In [3]: a
Out[3]:
array([[38, 85],
       [99, 19]])

In [4]: a_hires = np.kron(a, np.ones((2,2)))

In [5]: a_hires
Out[5]:
array([[ 38.,  38.,  85.,  85.],
       [ 38.,  38.,  85.,  85.],
       [ 99.,  99.,  19.,  19.],
       [ 99.,  99.,  19.,  19.]])
```